# Display only in stock options for configurable products on catalog pages in Magento

Tags: magento

I've managed to add options to configurable products on my catalog pages using the code found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21039/P45/#t167724. What I'd like to do now is only show the options that are available according to the stock of the simple product that the option is coming from.

For example, if I have a t-shirt (configurable product) that has various colors (simple products) and my red color is out of stock, red wouldn't be shown as an option when the configurable product is displayed.

What's the best way to do this?

**Update:**
For the sake of clarity, here is the relevant block of code from the link I posted.

```
<?php if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
    <?php $attValConfig = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray(); ?>
    <?php if(sizeof($attValConfig)): ?>
        <?php foreach($attValConfig as $attValConfigSingle): ?>
            <fieldset class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
                <label><?php echo $attValConfigSingle['label']; ?>:</label>
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $attValConfigSingle['attribute_id'] ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <?php foreach($attValConfigSingle['values'] as $attValConfigSingleVal): ?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $attValConfigSingleVal['value_index'] ?>"><?php echo $attValConfigSingleVal['label'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Since this code is simply getting all of the configurable options and displaying them, it doesn't check to see if the simple product that backs the configurable option is in stock. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you didn't check the links that sent you by comments. Here is the new one, hope you can fix your issue. http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tips/get-simple-products-of-a-configurable-product.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following ( do what you want returning result ) :

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($productId) // this line is wrong, don't care this
    ->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gteq' => 1));
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the code you provided. First, it seems that addIdFilter isn't a valid method on Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item_Collection. Second, it doesn't appear that calling `Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()` is returning any items. Any ideas?

Comment: @Luke I think you doing a mistakes, please take a look at the following link :
[How to show out of stock configurable options](http://www.ayasoftware.com/content/how-show-out-stock-configurable-options-magento)

Comment: Or try this :
`Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()`

Comment: It seems like the code you are posting assumes that I have the simple product loaded into $_product, which is not the case. Please see my updated question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just wondering why we are checking the quantity for stock status why dont't we look on stock availability of simple products.

I have achieved to show out of stock on configurable product according to stock status.
Now you can make product "out stock" and "in stock" through stock availability attribute of simple product.